# Serving HTTP and HTTPS from one installation

Tags: https, http

I've got a WordPress install that is serving up content via both HTTP and HTTPS. The site URL is configured as "http://www.example.com". This works for most situations - if a person requests a page at "https://www.example.com/page" the page is served up via HTTPS.

However, the challenge that I'm facing is that there are a number of WordPress template functions which pull the site URL (like get_bloginfo('stylesheet') ) and when they do that, they include "http://" in the returned results. Similarly, images that are inserted in the WYSIWYG editor have the "http://www.example.com..." path hard coded.

What I'd really like to do is find a way to define the base site URL as "//www.example.com", which would hopefully make everything work correctly. However, the WordPress admin fields won't support this.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: As long as all of your paths are coming from wordpress and everything in your code is marked up with `//` and not `http://` you should be fine.

Comment: This could also be an issue with the wordpress version you're using. I'm running 3.7.1 and things are working at full `https`.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to use .htaccess rules.

```
#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to force HTTPS (or redirect all non-HTTPS requests) the URLs in posts can be handled like this:

```
function content_ssl($content) {
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]))
    $content = ereg_replace("http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'content_ssl');
```

WordPress itself handles protocol matching.  Some plugins however do not.